# How can I change this query in so that return true if the select(*) count value is 2?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

I am not so into SQL and I have the following doubt. I have this query (I am using MySql):

```
SELECT count(*)                                AS exist
FROM MeteoForecast                             AS MF                         
WHERE 
     MF.localization_id = 22
AND
     DATE(MF.start_date) = DATE('2019/03/02')
```

returning the number of record into the **MeteoForecast** table as the **exist** field.

I want to modify it in this way:

if the value of the **count(*)** is equal to 2, it returns **true** (the **exist** field is true), otherwise the **exist** field value is false.

How can I implement this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a boolean expression:

```
SELECT (count(*) = 2) AS exist2
FROM MeteoForecast mf                       
WHERE MF.localization_id = 22 AND
      DATE(MF.start_date) = DATE('2019-03-02') ;
```

This expression actually returns true as "1" and false as "0".  Those are the numeric equivalents of the booleans *true* and *false* in MySQL.

Assuming that `start_date` has a time component, you should write this as:

```
SELECT (count(*) = 2) AS exist2
FROM MeteoForecast mf                       
WHERE MF.localization_id = 22 AND
      MF.start_date >= '2019-03-02' AND
      MF.stara_date < '2019-03-03' ;
```

This can take advantage of an index on `MeteoForecast(localization_id, start_date)`, so it can be much faster.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use case expression

```
SELECT case when count(*)=2 then true
else false end   AS exist
FROM MeteoForecast as MF                         
WHERE 
     MF.localization_id = 22
AND
     DATE(MF.start_date) = DATE('2019/03/02')
```